# Generate HTML files from e-Cobertura

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, eclipse-plugin, cobertura

I am using the e-cobertura plug-in for eclipse and am trying to generate the HTML file of the results. Anyone knows how to do that? What I am trying to do is basically do what cobertura-instrument.bat --destination is trying to do.

Thanks.